# Interactive plot - plot changing

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure

I am trying to create a GUI with uicontrol with sliders that will go on to section up my dataset depending on where the user sets the sliders on the data, How can I do this and use the values set by the user to trim down my dataset and use the smaller dataset for the rest of my function? This is what I have created so far

```
function myui

 MM = load('DATA.txt');
 X = MM(:,4);
  % Create a figure and axes
 f = figure('Visible','off');

 sldplot=plot(X)

  n = length(X);     


slider1 = uicontrol('Style', 'slider','Min',1,'Max',n,'Value',n,'Position', [100 20 120 20],'Callback', @slider1_Callback);

slider2 = uicontrol('Style', 'slider','Min',1,'Max',n,'Value',1,'Position', [400 20 120 20],'Callback', @slider2_Callback);
txt = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[400 45 120 20],'String','Second cut');
txt2 = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[100 45 120 20],'String','First cut');
addlistener(slider1, 'ContinuousValueChange', @myCallbackFcn1)
addlistener(slider2, 'ContinuousValueChange', @myCallbackFcn2)

    function myCallbackFcn1(source,callbackdata)

n2 = get(slider1,'Value');
n3 = get(slider2, 'Value');

plot(X(n2:n3))
set(sldplot,'xdata',X(n2:n3));

drawnow;
    end
    f.Visible = 'on';

    function slider1_Callback(source,callbackdata)
        val = get(slider1,'Value');

        Xnew = X(val:n);

    end

    function slider2_Callback(source,callbackdata)
        val2 = get(slider2,'Value');


        Xnew2 = X(1:val2);
    end


 end
```

however, this doesnt seem to be doing what I want. I get a static plot of my data and the sliders do no seem to move or zoom in on the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it. In the callbacks you actually don't need to call `plot` again since you got the handle to the plot right at the beginning of your function. What you need to do is simply update both the x- and ydata displayed.

I made some slight changes and it works fine now. I renamed the listener callbacks to give them more informative names and used dummy data for plotting. You will need to adjust to your own data but that won't be hard. I also swapped the initial values of both sliders.

Here is the code. I added `%// === NEW ===` at places where I added/modified stuff.

```
function myui
clear
clc
close all

%// Uncomment this and adjust the rest to fit with your data
%MM = load('DATA.txt');
%X = MM(:,4);

X = rand(1,100);

% Create a figure and axes
f = figure('Visible','off');

%// == NEW ==
%// Create an axes
hAxes = axes('Position',[.1 .15 .8 .8]);
sldplot=plot(X);

%// == NEW ==
%// Get axis limits to make sure the limits always stay the same
x_limit = get(gca,'XLim');
y_limit = get(gca,'YLim');

n = numel(X);

%// == NEW ==  I changed the values of the sliders
slider1 = uicontrol('Style', 'slider','Min',1,'Max',n,'Value',1,'Position', [100 5 120 20],'Callback', @slider1_Callback);

slider2 = uicontrol('Style', 'slider','Min',1,'Max',n,'Value',n,'Position', [400 5 120 20],'Callback', @slider2_Callback);
txt = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[400 30 120 15],'String','Second cut');
txt2 = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[100 30 120 15],'String','First cut');

%// ======== NEW ========

button1 = uicontrol('Style','push','position',[260 20 60 20],'String','Get Xnew','Callback',@ButtonCallback)

%// =====================

addlistener(slider1, 'ContinuousValueChange', @Slider1ListenerCallback);
addlistener(slider2, 'ContinuousValueChange', @Slider2ListenerCallback);
set(f,'Visible','on');

    function Slider1ListenerCallback(source,callbackdata)

        n2 = round(get(slider1,'Value'));
        n3 = round(get(slider2, 'Value'));

        %// == NEW ==
        %// Updata xdata only. DO NOT plot again
        set(sldplot,'xdata',(n2:n3),'ydata',X(n2:n3));

        %// == NEW ==
        set(gca,'XLim',x_limit,'YLim',y_limit)
        drawnow;
    end


    function slider1_Callback(source,callbackdata)
        n2 = round(get(slider1,'Value'));
        n3 = round(get(slider2, 'Value'));

        %// Updata xdata and ydata only. DO NOT plot again
        set(sldplot,'xdata',(n2:n3),'ydata',X(n2:n3));

        set(gca,'XLim',x_limit,'YLim',y_limit)
        drawnow;

    end


    function Slider2ListenerCallback(source,callbackdata)

        n2 = round(get(slider1,'Value'));
        n3 = round(get(slider2, 'Value'));

        %// Updata xdata and ydata only. DO NOT plot again
        set(sldplot,'xdata',(n2:n3),'ydata',X(n2:n3));

        set(gca,'XLim',x_limit,'YLim',y_limit)
        drawnow;
    end


    function slider2_Callback(source,callbackdata)
        n2 = round(get(slider1,'Value'));
        n3 = round(get(slider2, 'Value'));

        %// Updata xdata and ydata  only. DO NOT plot again
        set(sldplot,'xdata',(n2:n3),'ydata',X(n2:n3));

        set(gca,'XLim',x_limit,'YLim',y_limit)
        drawnow;

    end

%// ======== NEW ========
    function ButtonCallback(source,callbackdata)
        n2 = round(get(slider1,'Value'));
        n3 = round(get(slider2, 'Value'));

        Xnew = X(n2:n3)
    end
%// =====================
end
```

And a screenshot after moving both sliders:

[image]

In order to get `XNew` I added a pushbutton. Placing `Xnew = X(n2:n3)`right before the last `end` of the function caused an error because neither `n2` nor `n3` were defined when launching the function, since Matlab reads all the code from top to bottom. Therefore pressing a button to get the values is safer.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly and you explained it very well I understand exactly where I was going wrong now. How can I update my dataset to be the subset selected by the user calling it Xnew?

Comment: Awesome then glad to help! As for `Xnew` you can simply define it as `Xnew = X(n2:n3)` and that's it! Cheers!

Comment: I attempted to add that to the final line before the last end thinking that it would provide an output Xnew which is a subset of the initial dataset however it says that n2 and n3 are undefined

Comment: That's because `Xnew` is defined in a nested function and is not accessible from the main. The simplest workaround is to declare it `global` at the very beginning of the main function (myui; after clear/clc/close) and that should be fine.

Comment: Yes I thought of this but even when defining global Xnew at the start it still tells me that n2 and n3 are undefinied should I make them global at the start too because they are defined within a nested function and then used outside of it?

Comment: Ok tried to globalise n2 and n3 but still it tells me that Xnew is undefined

Comment: oh I meant to globalise `Xnew` haha sorry about the confusion

Comment: I did try that but I got this errorUndefined function or variable "n2".

Error in slider_plot (line 90)
Xnew = X(n2:n3);

Comment: Mhh that's weird! I'll check on that tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you for checking it for me :)

Comment: Please look at the edited answer. I added a bit of code and explanations. Basically added a pushbutton to create `Xnew`.

Comment: That's great! Thank you very mcuh! And I am guessing to save this new vector into a text file it would require, y = Xnew;
save('Newvalues.txt', 'y', '-ascii'); would this be placed in the final nested function

Comment: yep something like that! Have fun! :)